# Need to store handled exceptions globally without calling the save log method inside Every catch in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
    try
            {
                int c = 0;
                int a = 5 / c;   
             }
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
              
            }
```

Need to write Handled Exceptions globally in one place and without calling the errorlog method in each and every catch block in xamarin.forms and expect to get details in mainactivity for android and appdelegate for ios or any comman place in xamarin.forms

Comment: Your question is lil bit confusing, cant understand what you actually want... Can you try to expand you question in more details. And even i guess you arent looking for something like the answer mentioned below cuz AppCenter reports the app crash report, not the try catch logs automatically (*unless you add appcenter crash tracker in your catch block)

Comment: need to store not only crashes also need to store whatever handled exception comes inside the catch block.  hundreds of catch blocks in my application so I don't want to call the error log method in each and every catch block. whenever catch the exception the exception details need to store in a file globally

Comment: ohh i did same what you are thinking of, for that i created an table for logs in my database & a repository to add exception traces, i calls the add method of  my repo in every catch block. And Btw i think thats not possible to gather all exceptions globally as you want

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could use **App Center** . App Center Crashes will automatically generate a crash log every time your app crashes. The log is first written to the device's storage and when the user starts the app again, the crash report will be sent to App Center. Collecting crashes works for both beta and live apps, i.e. those submitted to the App Store. Crash logs contain valuable information for you to help fix the crash.

App Center Crashes provides you with an API to generate a test crash for easy testing of the SDK. This API checks for debug vs release configurations. So you can only use it when debugging as it won't work for release apps.

```
Crashes.GenerateTestCrash();
```

If your app crashed previously, you can get details about the last crash.

```
ErrorReport crashReport = await Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync();
```

Set this callback if you want to decide if a particular crash needs to be processed or not. For example, there could be a system level crash that you'd want to ignore and that you don't want to send to App Center.

```
Crashes.ShouldProcessErrorReport = (ErrorReport report) =>
{
    // Check the report in here and return true or false depending on the ErrorReport.
    return true;
};
```

For more details about App Center you could check [Get Started with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) .